# How to bind one service to multiple apps

Tags: android, service

We are very new to Android programming with services. We managed to make a service run with one app. Now, we have one owner app "AppA" that has initiated the service and there is another app "AppB" which wants to use the service. So how do we bind to this app "AppB" to the same running service? Should there be multiple instances of the service (is this possible?) created or can we bind multiple apps to the same instance of the service?

We have created a function called initservice() in order to bind the activity to the service.

Owner App A's code in initService():

```
connection = new SampleServiceConnection();
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.example.basicstuff",com.example.basicstuff.SampleService.class.getName());
this.startService(i);
boolean ret = bindService(i, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
Log.d(TAG, "initService() bound with " + ret);
```

The SampleServiceConnection class is the class which implements ServiceConnection class of Andorid. I have already implemented onServiceConnected() and onServiceDisconnected() functions. My first owner app, "AppA" is the package com.example.basicstuff and the class which extends the Service class is SampleService. After executing bindService() function, the LogCat displays "initService() bound with true".

I have also created an .aidl file called ISampleService.

App B's code in initService()

```
connection = new SampleServiceConnection();
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.GameBook_Chat.ISampleService");
System.out.println(this.startService(i));
System.out.println("service running");
boolean ret = bindService(i, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
Log.d(TAG, "initService() bound with " + ret);
```

My second package name is com.example.GameBook_Chat which wants to communicate with the same service running in the above code. Upon execution of bindService() function the LogCat service says "initService() bound with false"

So basically I am not able to make the second app communicate with the service. Could someone tell me what corrections can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Every call to `bindService()` results in a call to the Service's `onBind()` method.  The service can feel free to return the same `IBinder`-implementing object to each client.  You can use methods like `checkCallingPermission()` to authenticate any call or `getCallingUid()` if you just want to know who the caller is.